# PageRank of the highest rank page (Directed graph)

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, page-rank

Suppose the hyperlink matrix of a directed graph is given as follows:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\ \:\:\:0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}\\ \:\:\:0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}\\ \:\:\:\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}\\ \:\:\:\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

How to find the PageRank of the highest rank page?

I started with the initial vector as $x =(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$ and then started the iterative process finding $Ax,A^2x.$

Answer (score 0):

First note that by a straightforward calculation all entries of the third power $A^3$ are positive, thus $A$ is primitive. Further, if one interprets the $(i,j)$ entry of $A$ as the $j$th webpage containing a hyperlink to the $i$th webpage, the associated network of webpages is strongly connected as it has the cycle

$$1\mapsto 5\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto 1,$$

thus $A$ is also irreducible. Hence by Perron-Frobenius theory $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A$.

Then to find the PageRank vector in this case one would need to solve the equation

$$Av = v$$

for $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)$ such that $v_i\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^5 v_i=1$. [Row reducing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=row%20reduce%20%7B%7B-1%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%2C%201%2F2%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%20-1%2C%200%2C%201%2F2%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2F2%2C%20-1%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F2%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%2C%20-1%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F2%2C%201%2F2%2C%201%2F3%2C%200%2C%20-1%7D%7D) the matrix $A-I$, one obtains

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{32}{45} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{11}{15} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{14}{15} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thus any eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$ is of the form

$$(32k,36k,33k,42k,45k)$$

for $k$ an arbitrary real number. The coefficients add up to $188$, thus choosing $k=1/188$ gives the [PageRank vector](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%2C%201%2F2%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%201%2F2%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2F2%2C%200%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F2%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%2C%200%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F2%2C%201%2F2%2C%201%2F3%2C%200%2C%200%7D%7D%20*%20%7B%7B32%2F188%7D%2C%20%7B36%2F188%7D%2C%20%7B33%2F188%7D%2C%20%7B42%2F188%7D%2C%20%7B45%2F188%7D%7D):

$$\text{PR} = (32/188,36/188,33/188,42/188,45/188)$$

Of course by Perron-Frobenius theory iterates of any initial probability vector ought to converge to the PageRank vector, but it seems computing iterates is not significantly easier in this case, as opposed to computing the stationary state.